# How can I get authlogic to use the Rails session instead of its own cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, authlogic

I would like authogic to never set a `user_credentials` cookie, and only use the standard Rails session cookie.

I see `Session` is included in `Authlogic::Session::Session::Base` after `Cookies`. If I log into my app and then delete the `user_credentials` cookie, I still stay logged in. So apparently authlogic is storing the credentials in both places and checking both places? Or ignoring the cookie but still setting it? How can I have it never set or reference the `user_credentials` cookie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the answer to my question here…

[How can I remove callbacks inserted by vendor code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240914/how-can-i-remove-callbacks-inserted-by-vendor-code/3241242)

…the answer to THIS question is to do this above my UserSession definition:

```
Authlogic::Session::Base.after_save.delete_if{ |callback| callback.method == :save_cookie }
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

Comment: I got this to work so the user_credentials cookie isn't saved but it seems like Authlogic needs this cookie, instead of the ability to just use the Rails session. Any insight here?

Comment: @grant Did you ever get any insight on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use vendored authlogic then you can prevent to user_credentials cookie by using and change some code on save_cookie method on "authlogic-2.1.5/lib/authlogic/session/cookies.rb"

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great start.