# How can I remove callbacks inserted by vendor code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, callback

A gem I am using inserts an after_save callback that I would like to remove. It seems to me it would be cleaner to delete a symbol from an array than to fix the problem with a monkeypatch. How can I access the array of callbacks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  # Don't use cookie AuthLogic behaviour
  skip_callback :persist, :persist_by_cookie
  skip_callback :after_save, :save_cookie
  skip_callback :after_destroy, :destroy_cookie
end
```

Comment: thanks-- this looks much better than my solution :-) i'm on a rails 2 project for now though, upgrading to rails 3 soon, i'll try it then.

Comment: For me (rails 3.1) I had to use `skip_callback :destroy, :after, :destroy_cookie` (paraphrasing for my own use-case)

Answer (score 2):

the `after_save` array is accessible via `Model.after_save`, it is an array of `ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback` objects.  You could run this from within the model

```
self.after_save.delete_if{|callback| callback.method == :do_something_callback}
```

Comment: Looks good… but where/when would I do that? Within the class definition?

Comment: I would say so, right with your other callbacks.  As long as it is loaded after your plugin then it should be good to go.

Comment: If you're interested, here's the solution I ended up with for my particular problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162867/how-can-i-get-authlogic-to-use-the-rails-session-instead-of-its-own-cookie

Comment: This solution works for Rails 2. For Rails 3, w1rele55's is better.