# Rails: Setting and deleting additional cookies when using Switch User gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I'm using the `switch_user` gem to have the possibility of changing to another user. However, I want to be able to set or delete cookies when switching to a user. I've not been able to do so, and the documentation on `switch_user` doesn't mention this. Perhaps it's got more to do with my authentication gem, `authlogic` (in the `switch_user` configuration file you have to specify which authorization provider you're using), but I don't know. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better choice to store the information in the session instead of cookie because of cookie overflow, as there is a 4KB limit.

More information about this can be found here: [Cookie overflow in rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473808/cookie-overflow-in-rails-application)

Another approach would be using the rack session: http://pivotallabs.com/fast-user-switching-with-devise/

Comment: I will try to be careful about cookie overflow. Let's assume I store the information in the session. I still can't find a way to do it when switching a user

Comment: then you would have to play around with authlogic, example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162867/how-can-i-get-authlogic-to-use-the-rails-session-instead-of-its-own-cookie

Comment: That example is good, but only to avoid creating the default Authlogic cookie. I want to retain it and also add additional cookies